# Jquery DataTable não funciona

Tags: asp.net, jquery-datatables

Criei em meu sistema uma tabela utilizando a biblioteca jquery datatable, porém não está funcionando. Ao final da view fiz a declaração de código em javascript, porém o estilo não é aplicado.

Segue código abaixo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
     $('.table').dataTable({
            "order": [[1, "asc"]]
        });
    });
</script>
```

E css:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/content/DataTables/css/datatables.bootstrap.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Obs: Uso 3 datatables, somente em uma não funciona e o código está idêntico para os 3 casos.

Comment: "$('.table')" Existe realmente essa classe table? Ou você está tentando manipular a table? Se for isso mude para `$('table')`

Answer (score 1):

O erro pode estar no html da tabela. Se ele não estiver correto `(table,thead,tbody)` pode acontecer de não inicializar corretamente.